# OutputCache VaryByCustom cookie value

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, cookies, outputcache

Is there a way to set the value of an OutputCache based on a cookie value?

For simplicities sake, this is my method

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByParam = "None", VaryByCustom = "ztest")]
public ViewResult Index()
{
     return View();
}
```

My **Global.asax** has this (in order to override the GetVaryByCustomString method

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    if (custom == "ztest")
    {
        HttpCookie ztest = context.Request.Cookies["ztest"];
        if (ztest != null)
        {
            return ztest.Value;
        }
    }

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

I can verify that my browser has the **ztest** cookie, but when I debug the Index method, I hit the breakpoint every time (meaning that the cache isn't working).

The HttpResponse has no outbound cookies, so this point would not apply: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.shareable(v=vs.110).aspx

> If a given HttpResponse contains one or more outbound cookies with Shareable is set to false (the default value), output caching will be suppressed for the response. This prevents cookies that contain potentially sensitive information from being cached in the response and sent to multiple clients. To allow a response containing cookies to be cached, configure caching normally for the response, such as using the OutputCache directive or MVC's [OutputCache] attribute, and set all outbound cookies to have Shareable set to true.

Comment: did you tried to check `HttpCookie.Shareable = true`  ? , in your case it would be like `cookie.Shareable = true; `

Comment: Do you mean check if the Shareable value is true in the `GetVaryByCustomString` method?

Comment: first check usually by default it will `false` , try to change to `true`

Comment: By default the value is false when I pull the cookie from the context.Request

Comment: yes it would be , try to keep it `true` and verify once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subtle answer is no.

The Explained answer is as follows:

**The reason output cache doesn't play nice with cookies**

So the reason the output cache will not cache a response with cookies is that a cookie could be user-specific (e.g. authentication, analytical tracking, etc.). If one or more cookies with the property `HttpCookie.Shareable = false`, then the output cache considers the response uncacheable.

**Solution:**

There are some workarounds though, The output cache caches the response headers and content together and doesn't provide any hooks to modify these before sending them back to the user.However,there is a way to provide the ability to change before cached response's headers before they are sent back to the user.
One of them requires the *Fasterflect nuget package*.

I have an example of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Caching;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Caching;
using Fasterflect;

namespace CustomOutputCache
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An output cache provider that has ability to modify the http header collection before a cached response is served back to the user.
    /// </summary>
    public class HeaderModOutputCacheProvider : OutputCacheProvider
    {
        private static readonly Type OutputCacheEntryType, HttpCachePolicySettingsType;
        private static readonly Type[] ParameterTypes;

        public static event EventHandler<CachedRequestEventArgs> RequestServedFromCache;

        static HeaderModOutputCacheProvider()
        {
            var systemWeb = typeof(HttpContext).Assembly;
            OutputCacheEntryType = systemWeb.GetType("System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheEntry");
            HttpCachePolicySettingsType = systemWeb.GetType("System.Web.HttpCachePolicySettings");
            ParameterTypes = new[]{
                typeof(Guid),
                HttpCachePolicySettingsType,
                typeof(string),
                typeof(string) ,
                typeof(string[]),
                typeof(int),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(List<HeaderElement>),
                typeof(List<ResponseElement>)
            };
        }

        private readonly ObjectCache _objectCache;

        public HeaderModOutputCacheProvider()
        {
            _objectCache = new MemoryCache("output-cache");
        }

        #region OutputCacheProvider implementation

        public override object Get(string key)
        {
            var cachedValue = _objectCache.Get(key);

            if (cachedValue == null)
                return null;

            if (cachedValue.GetType() != OutputCacheEntryType)
                return cachedValue;

            var cloned = CloneOutputCacheEntry(cachedValue);

            if (RequestServedFromCache != null)
            {
                var args = new CachedRequestEventArgs(cloned.HeaderElements);
                RequestServedFromCache(this, args);
            }

            return cloned;
        }

        public override object Add(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry)
        {
            _objectCache.Set(key, entry, new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = utcExpiry });
            return entry;
        }

        public override void Set(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry)
        {
            _objectCache.Set(key, entry, new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = utcExpiry });
        }

        public override void Remove(string key)
        {
            _objectCache.Remove(key);
        }

        #endregion

        private IOutputCacheEntry CloneOutputCacheEntry(object toClone)
        {
            var parameterValues = new[]
            {
                toClone.GetFieldValue("_cachedVaryId", Flags.InstancePrivate),
                toClone.GetFieldValue("_settings", Flags.InstancePrivate),
                toClone.GetFieldValue("_kernelCacheUrl", Flags.InstancePrivate),
                toClone.GetFieldValue("_dependenciesKey", Flags.InstancePrivate),
                toClone.GetFieldValue("_dependencies", Flags.InstancePrivate),
                toClone.GetFieldValue("_statusCode", Flags.InstancePrivate),
                toClone.GetFieldValue("_statusDescription", Flags.InstancePrivate),
                CloneHeaders((List<HeaderElement>)toClone.GetFieldValue("_headerElements", Flags.InstancePrivate)),
                toClone.GetFieldValue("_responseElements", Flags.InstancePrivate)
            };

            return (IOutputCacheEntry)OutputCacheEntryType.CreateInstance(
                parameterTypes: ParameterTypes,
                parameters: parameterValues
            );
        }

        private List<HeaderElement> CloneHeaders(List<HeaderElement> toClone)
        {
            return new List<HeaderElement>(toClone);
        }
    }

    public class CachedRequestEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public CachedRequestEventArgs(List<HeaderElement> headers)
        {
            Headers = headers;
        }
        public List<HeaderElement> Headers { get; private set; }

        public void AddCookies(HttpCookieCollection cookies)
        {
            foreach (var cookie in cookies.AllKeys.Select(c => cookies[c]))
            {
                //more reflection unpleasantness :(
                var header = cookie.CallMethod("GetSetCookieHeader", Flags.InstanceAnyVisibility, HttpContext.Current);
                Headers.Add(new HeaderElement((string)header.GetPropertyValue("Name"), (string)header.GetPropertyValue("Value")));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Wire it up this way:

```
<system.web>
  <caching>
      <outputCache defaultProvider="HeaderModOutputCacheProvider">
        <providers>
          <add name="HeaderModOutputCacheProvider" type="CustomOutputCache.HeaderModOutputCacheProvider"/>
        </providers>
      </outputCache>
    </caching>
  </system.web>
```

And use it this way:

```
HeaderModOutputCacheProvider.RequestServedFromCache += RequestServedFromCache;

HeaderModOutputCacheProvider.RequestServedFromCache += (sender, e) =>
{
    e.AddCookies(new HttpCookieCollection
    {
        new HttpCookie("key", "value")
    });
};
```

I don't know if it answers you question, but I hope it points to the right direction.

Comment: I did not end up using your solution, but instead ended up removing `OutputCache` from the code that depended on the value of cookies